# Mongodb database design for twitter data

Tags: mongodb, api, twitter, database

I am using twitter `public streaming api` and `timeline api` to fetch data. `streaming api` continuously dumps data to the server for any `search keyword` while timeline api returns timeline of a `particular user` . as it can be clearly seen data from both api's can become very lagre quickly , what would be the correct DB structure if i am using mongoDB.

What I think of is creating two separate `databases` each for `streaming api` and for `timeline api` then under each database create a `collection` for every user ( because if i use a single collection for storing all users fetching data will take a lot of time) . In normal scenario creating a different collection for every user doesn't make sense but what about for this particular usecase? How can I model the design properly ?